# Is there a way to share a CuPy array between two python processes?

Tags: cupy

is there a way to share the same CuPy array between two Python processes without replicating it?
For NumPy, there is the  [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) mechanism. Is there a similar mechanism for CuPy?